# How delete interfaces from snmp iflist oid?

Tags: snmp, mib

This is the output of `snmpwalk`:

```
snmpwalk -c public -v2c localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.2 
IF-MIB::ifNumber.0 = INTEGER: 5
IF-MIB::ifIndex.1 = INTEGER: 1
IF-MIB::ifIndex.2 = INTEGER: 2
IF-MIB::ifIndex.3 = INTEGER: 3
IF-MIB::ifIndex.4 = INTEGER: 4
IF-MIB::ifIndex.5 = INTEGER: 5
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = STRING: gbeth0
IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = STRING: gbeth1
IF-MIB::ifDescr.3 = STRING: gbeth2
IF-MIB::ifDescr.4 = STRING: gbeth3
IF-MIB::ifDescr.5 = STRING: defloopback
```

I want to delete the ifIndex.5, when I run snmpwalk.

How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to process the output line by line (Linux shell):

```
snmpwalk -c public -v2c localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.2 | sed 1d | \
while read i
do
    if [[ $i != *"5"* ]]; then
      echo $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: KomiaginThank you for your reply. Actually I check the output in monitoring softwares too, and I see these interfaces in it. So I think the snmp itself should modify. The monitoring software that i use is solarwinds.

Comment: Sure, you cannot physically remove the network interface from the agent/device. You can only ignore it in snmp walk output.

Comment: @F.M I don't know whether that was a serious suggestion, but I certainly wouldn't recommend changing the Net-SNMP source code just to filter out a SNMP walk result that you don't like. Why not instruct your monitoring software to perform the needful according to your requirements? Or just simply ignore the unwanted entry?